# CSS space before selector

Tags: html, css

I was struggling to understand why this simple CSS class selector was not being picked by my HTML element.

```
.label-hi :before {
    color:green;
    content: "Hi ! ";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The space between simple selectors is a [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators) in CSS. If it were two ordinary selectors separated with space, it would mean 'element matching the second selector, placed anywhere inside the element matching the first selector'. Since the second selector is a pseudo element, the whole selector is equivalent to `.label-hi *:before`, potentially inserting something into *any* element *inside* the element with class `label-hi`.

Comment: Yeah there's no hover. But the "descendant combinator" point still applies. With the space, we're selecting a *child* of `.label-hi` and putting stuff before it. http://jsfiddle.net/GtTcn/4/

Comment: Fantastic; my original comment deleted (as will this be, momentarily).

Answer (score 1):

So I realized that for this specific selectors I cannot have any space between the class name and the `:` This means that removing the empty space my CSS class is picked :

```
.label-hi:before {
    color:green;
    content: "Hi ! ";
}
```

In regular classes that space does not make any difference.

Sample here : http://jsfiddle.net/GtTcn/

Comment: The space, in CSS, is *always* important as it defines an ancestor-descendant relationship. If you [add a child element](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GtTcn/2/), or [multiple descendants](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GtTcn/3/) to the `label` you'll see this.