# CSS :not() Selector failure

Tags: css

Recently, when I was using the CSS:not selector, I found a problem with spaces. Maybe I have a problem with the selector's understanding, please help me to answer。
I want to select all elements except the seventh element in the main element。

```css
        main:not(section:nth-child(7)){                    
            width: 100px;             
            height: 100px;
            background-color: red;
            margin: 10px;
        }
```

```html
    <main>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>seven</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
    </main>
```

It is invalid after selection, but it will be valid after adding a space before the: not selector. This is the reason？

```css
        main :not(section:nth-child(7)){                    
            width: 100px;             
            height: 100px;
            background-color: red;
            margin: 10px;
        }
```

```html
    <main>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>seven</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
    </main>
```

And I tried to select with sibling elements, but also found the space problem. Contrary to the above, adding spaces is invalid, deleting spaces is effective.

```css
        section :not(section:nth-child(7)){                    
            width: 100px;             
            height: 100px;
            background-color: red;
            margin: 10px;
        }
```

```html
    <main>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>seven</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
    </main>
```

The above code is invalid after adding a space before the not selector。

```css
        section:not(section:nth-child(7)){                    
            width: 100px;             
            height: 100px;
            background-color: red;
            margin: 10px;
        }
```

```html
    <main>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>seven</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
    </main>
```

Delete: the space in front of the not selector will be effective。

Comment: Please use this style. "section:not(:nth-child(7))"

Comment: Is the grammar wrong in other styles? Or is there any difference that prevents him from using it correctly？

Comment: The difference between first and second is related with CSS Combinators.
And the third and fourth are wrong.

Comment: The following post could clear you more about this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624551/css-space-before-selector

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Main is just parent element you can directly use the select tag as a  selector and apply not and nth-of-type

this article will give you information about **:nth-child()** vs **:nth-of-child()**

if you found this will help you then please give me like

```css
main section:not(:nth-of-type(7)){
    width: 100px;             
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<main>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>seven</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
        <section>1</section>
    </main>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it will be very helpful for me to understand CSS selectors!